# Angularjs datetime-picker timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, datetime, angular-material

I am using [angular-material-datetimepicker](http://logbon72.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/) in my modal to enter date and time. However, angular sends all data server side in json and that changes the time to UTC. On reloading my client side, UTC time is displayed which I do not want. How do I make the client display my local time (GMT +2 in my case)? How do I manipulate only the date part of the json string? I've seen confusing solutions on other similar SO q's and forums. Thanks.

**On the modal html**

```
        <div class="time">
           <md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder start_time">
              <label>Start Date/Time</label>
              <input mdc-datetime-picker="" date="true" time="true" type="text" id="datetime" placeholder="Start" min-date="date" format="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm" ng-model="Project.StartAt" class=" md-input">
           </md-input-container>

           <md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder endtime">
              <label>End Date/Time</label>
              <input mdc-datetime-picker="" date="true" time="true" type="text" id="datetime" placeholder="End" min-date="date" format="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm" ng-model="Project.EndAt" class=" md-input">
           </md-input-container>
        </div>
```

**angular**

```
$scope.editProject = function(data) {
        $scope.showSelected = true;
        $scope.SelectedProject = data;
        var fromDate = moment(data.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');
        var endDate  = moment(data.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');

        $scope.Project = { 
            ProjectID : data.projectID, 
            Client : data.client,
            Title : data.title,
            Description: data.description,
            Employees: data.employees,
            StartAt : fromDate,
            EndAt : endDate,
            IsFullDay : false
        }
        $scope.ShowModal()
    },

$scope.ShowModal = function(){
        $scope.option = {
            templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
            controller: 'modalController',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                Project : function () { 
                    return $scope.Project;
                },
                SelectedProject : function () { 
                    return $scope.SelectedProject;
                },
                projects: function () {
                    return $ctrl.projects;
                }
            }
        };

    var modal = $uibModal.open($scope.option);
        modal.result.then(function (data) { 

           $scope.Project = data.project; 
            switch (data.operation){
               case 'Save':
                    //Save here
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/',
                        data: $scope.Project
                    }).then(function(response){
                        if(response.data.status){                                
                            $scope.projects.push(Project);
                        }
                    })
                    break;
```

Comment: I instead resolved by adding moment timezone library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply filter for that like :

```
$scope.yourDate= $filter('date')(new Date($scope.yourDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // Try different format as per your requirement
```

> Don't forget to inject dependency $filter.

Comment: I've edited the angular above to show the performing function. Not sure I understand from your solution how to go about it as I am using an external component. Could you show according to my set up?